# Is jruby REXML and REXML::Document thread safe?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety, jruby

I just wonder whether REXML library (especially REXML::Document) is thread safe in jruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not perfectly thread-safe: there are some class variables in the REXML classes that could be modified at any time by more than one thread (e.g., Document::entity_expansion_limit). However, most of the code is thread safe (no autoloading, for example); if you are not using those dangerous bites, you can use it without any problem.

Or you could use Nokogiri that is [thread-safe by design](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/mechanize-users/2009-September/000449.html) (modulo bugs).